# Laravel 5 automatically session expiring

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, path

I am developing an application in laravel 5, when the user logins i am showing a view file which contains more than 100 images and showing one after the with next and previous buttons using jquery. Everything is working fine if images path is given correct.

```
$img = $question_images[$i];
$img_path = url("frontend/questions/".$img);
$new_question = str_ireplace($img,"<img src='$img_path' class='img-responsive' oncontextmenu='return false' draggable='false'>",$new_question);
```

This is my logic as per the requirement. For development changes i moved all the images to **questions_old** folder and now **questions** folder is empty. Now the view file doesn't show images which i know, but when i refresh the page it is automatically expiring session and loggs out the user, how is this happening ? when images are in **questions** folder everything is working fine. How and why this wrong images path makes session out.?

Comment: Do you mean Auth::logout(); ?

Comment: First of all make sure the session is indeed expiring and this is not a side-effect of cookies being evicted/destroyed somehow (check if the session id changed and if the old session is still valid in the session store).

Comment: @AlexSlipknot no this is not related to Auth.